# How can I find element in shadow DOM in safari? (Polymer)

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I use paper-input on Polymer, in chrome I can find element in shadow DOM

```
var input = this.$.input.querySelector(':host /deep/ input')
```

But this doesn't work in Safari. I think a problem in "/deep/".
How can I find element in Safari?

Answer (score 1):

Shadow DOM and all connected selectors are not supported in any browser except Chrome, Opera and Andriod (http://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdom). That's why in Polymer 1 we have the shady DOM.

Now the guys from Polymer also thought about the benefits of a shadow DOM (no bleeding of design), so they came up with shady DOM. And this has to sides:

1. If you place CSS into your template – especially the CSS Selectors – it get's rewritten. That's why things like `:host`, `/deep/` or `::shadow` work.
2. If you use your selectors in JS, like you do, you don't have to bother with these special selectors. Just have a look at the DOM and go for it. So, for instance `document.querySelectorAll('paper-input')` gets you all `paper-input` elements, no matter where they are residing in the DOM.